# How was the movie Vaiana translated into the European English version?

Tags: voice-acting, moana

We already know that Moana is called Vaiana in all the European countries. I am from a German-speaking country but watched the movie in English, which I thought was the original version but the main character is also called Vaiana there.

So how did they translate only that name?

I don't think they recorded every version of "Vaiana" and replaced it, could it have been done by a computer or did the producers originally make a Vaiana and a Moana Version?

Comment: The voices are recorded **multiple** times, it's quite likely that there was a Vaiana version recorded *at the same time* as the Moana versions. The same thing was done for Zootopia where it was changed to Zootroplis

Comment: By far not in all European countries.

Answer (score 2):

[Trivia section](https://imdb.com/title/tt3521164/trivia) on IMDb states (without references though) that

> In many European countries, the title and main character were changed to Vaiana to avoid referencing Italian actress Moana Pozzi. **The voice actors had to come back and re-record some of their lines.**